# Jquery function can't run on new elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I created a list consist of item with inputs as follows.

In the jquery I created several functions (change `Formula` text according to `Balance` value, change the format of `Balance` input, and delete the list item). Initially all the function works, but when I click `Add Item +` and try to trigger the functions on new item list it doesn't work.

I don't know why this happened. Any help appreciated! :)

```js
var tempMulti;

$(document).ready(function() {
  resizeMultiPadding();
  tempMulti = $(".multi-list").html();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  resizeMultiPadding();
});

function resizeMultiPadding() {
  if ($(window).width() >= 576) {
    var padding =  $(window).width() * 0.04;
    $(".multi-col").css({"padding-right": padding + "px"});
    $(".multi-col:last-child").css({"padding-right": "0"});
    $(".multi-list-each-delete").html("<i class='fas fa-trash'></i>");
  }
  else {
    $(".multi-list-each-delete").html("<a class='button footer-btn text-btn'><span><i class='fas fa-trash'></i>Delete</span></a>");
  }
}

$(".spinner-up").click(function() {
  var amount = parseInt($(this).parent().prev().prev().val()) || 0;
  amount += 1;
  $(this).parent().prev().prev().val(amount);
});

$(".spinner-down").click(function() {
  var value = $(this).parent().prev().prev().val();
  var amount = parseInt(value) || 0;
  if (amount > 0) {
    amount -= 1; 
  }
  $(this).parent().prev().prev().val(amount);
});

(function($, undefined) {
  "use strict";
  $(function() {
    var $form = $("#form-amount-input, .balance-group");
    var $input = $form.find("input");
    $input.on("keyup", function(event) {
    var selection = window.getSelection().toString();
    if (selection !== "") {
      return;
    }
    if ($.inArray(event.keyCode, [38,40,37,39]) !== -1) {
      return;
    }
    var $this = $(this);
    var input = $this.val();
    input = input.replace(/[\D\s\._\-]+/g, "");
    input = input ? parseInt(input, 10) : 0;
    var formatted = input.toLocaleString("en-US");
    $this.val(formatted);
    $this.parent().parent().parent().find(".panel-data-value").text("Formula + " + formatted + ".00");
    if (formatted == "0") {
      $this.parent().parent().parent().find(".panel-data-value").text("Formula");
    }
  });
  });
})(jQuery);

$(".add-multi").click(function() {
  $(".multi-list").prepend(tempMulti);
});

$(".multi-list-each-delete").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

```css
.form {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 768px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
 font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #0099ff;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.input-text {
  height: 34px;
  border: solid 1px #c4c4c4;
  width: 366px;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 0 12px 0 12px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  color: #333;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.input-text:focus {
  border: solid 1px #00c983 !important; 
}

::placeholder {
  color: #c4c4c4; 
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: left !important;
}

.form-input-label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  color: #333;
}

.input-disabled {
  background-color: #eee; 
}

.form-unit {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.input-select-btn {
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 34px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: -999;
}

.dropdown-btn-wrapper-clear {
  border-left: solid 1px #c4c4c4; 
}

.input-select-btn i {
  color: #666 !important; 
}

.on-disabled-btn {
  border: solid 1px #c4c4c4;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.input-select-btn i {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #333;
}

.form-row {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.form-divided {
  display: inline-block;
}

.form-divided-left {
  margin-right: 32px;
}

.btn-label {
  background-color: #eee; 
}

.spinner-group {
  position: absolute; 
  width: 16px;
  height: 26px;
  top: 4px;
  right: 44px;
}

.spinner-up,
.spinner-down {
  height: 13px;
  line-height: 13px;
  display: block;
}

.spinner-down {
  top: 12px !important; 
}

.spinner-up i,
.spinner-down i {
  line-height: 13px;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  margin: 0; 
}

.input-with-spinner {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 32px; 
}

#amount-input {
  width: 100% !important; 
}

.amount-spinner-group {
  right: 10px; 
}

.add-multi {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  border: dashed 2px #eaeaea;
  font-size: 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.add-multi:hover {
  background-color: #f8f8f8; 
}

.add-multi i {
  font-size: 10px; 
  transform: translateY(-1px);
  margin-left: 4px;
}

.multi-list-each {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 16px 24px 12px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.multi-list-each input {
  background-color: #fff; 
}

.multi-form-group {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.multi-form-group input { 
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.spinner-group-year {
  right: 2px; 
}

#balance-currency {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.multi-col {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-right: 16px;
  padding-left: 16px;
}

.multi-col:first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.multi-col:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}

.multi-col input {
  margin-bottom: 0; 
}

.multi-list-each-delete {
  position: absolute; 
  right: 24px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.multi-list-each-delete i {
  font-size: 12px; 
}

@media (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 576px) {
  .form {
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-right: 16px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .form-divided-left {
    margin-right: 24px;
  }
  
  .form-divided {
    width: calc(50% - 14px);
  }
  
  .input-text,
  textarea {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .input-select-btn {
    right: 0;
  }
  
  .labeled-row {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .form-unit .select2-container, .form-unit .select2-selection {
      width: 100% !important;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .form {
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-right: 16px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .form-divided {
    display: block; 
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .form-divided-left {
    margin-right: 0; 
  }
  
  .input-text,
  textarea {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .labeled-row {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .form-unit .select2-container, .form-unit .select2-selection {
      width: 100% !important;
  }
  
  .multi-col {
    margin-bottom: 16px; 
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
  }
  
  .multi-list-each-delete {
    bottom: 8px;
    top: auto;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    text-align: center;
    color: #999;
  }
  
  .multi-list-each-delete .button:hover {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #999;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.11/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-p2jx59pefphTFIpeqCcISO9MdVfIm4pNnsL08A6v5vaQc4owkQqxMV8kg4Yvhaw/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="form">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-unit">
      <div class="multi-attribute">
        <label class="form-input-label">Multi-Attributes Input</label>
        <div class="add-multi">Add item <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></div>
        <ul class="multi-list">
          <li class="multi-list-each">
            <div class="col-33 multi-col">
              <label class="form-input-label">Year</label>
              <div class="multi-form-group">
                <input class="year-input input-text input-with-spinner" type="number" min="0" placeholder="Add year">
                <a />
                <div class="spinner-group spinner-group-year">
                  <a class="spinner-up"><i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i></a>
                  <a class="spinner-down"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-33 multi-col">
              <label class="form-input-label">Balance Increase</label>
              <div class="balance-group multi-form-group">
                <input class="balance-input input-text input-with-spinner" type="text" placeholder="Add balance">
                <a />
                <div class="spinner-group spinner-group-year">
                  <a class="spinner-up"><i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i></a>
                  <a class="spinner-down"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-33 multi-col">
              <div class="panel-data panel-data-vertical">
                <div class="panel-data-label">
                  Total Balance
                </div>
                <div class="panel-data-value">
                  Formula
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="multi-list-each-delete"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery works with the DOM that's loaded on `$(document).ready`. To target new elements you need to write your functions like this:

```
$(document).on('handler', '#my-new-element-id', function()
{
    alert('clicked the new guy')
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Change `$(".spinner-up")` to `$(document).on("click",".spinner-up",function() {`

Same goes for some of your other elements.

**working demo**

```js
var tempMulti;

$(document).ready(function() {
  resizeMultiPadding();
  tempMulti = $(".multi-list").html();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  resizeMultiPadding();
});

function resizeMultiPadding() {
  if ($(window).width() >= 576) {
    var padding =  $(window).width() * 0.04;
    $(".multi-col").css({"padding-right": padding + "px"});
    $(".multi-col:last-child").css({"padding-right": "0"});
    $(".multi-list-each-delete").html("<i class='fas fa-trash'></i>");
  }
  else {
    $(".multi-list-each-delete").html("<a class='button footer-btn text-btn'><span><i class='fas fa-trash'></i>Delete</span></a>");
  }
}

$(document).on("click",".spinner-up",function() {
  var amount = parseInt($(this).parent().prev().prev().val()) || 0;
  amount += 1;
  $(this).parent().prev().prev().val(amount);
});

$(document).on("click",".spinner-down",function() {
  var value = $(this).parent().prev().prev().val();
  var amount = parseInt(value) || 0;
  if (amount > 0) {
    amount -= 1; 
  }
  $(this).parent().prev().prev().val(amount);
});

(function($, undefined) {
  "use strict";
  $(function() {
    var $form = $("#form-amount-input, .balance-group");
    var $input = $form.find("input");
    $input.on("keyup", function(event) {
    var selection = window.getSelection().toString();
    if (selection !== "") {
      return;
    }
    if ($.inArray(event.keyCode, [38,40,37,39]) !== -1) {
      return;
    }
    var $this = $(this);
    var input = $this.val();
    input = input.replace(/[\D\s\._\-]+/g, "");
    input = input ? parseInt(input, 10) : 0;
    var formatted = input.toLocaleString("en-US");
    $this.val(formatted);
    $this.parent().parent().parent().find(".panel-data-value").text("Formula + " + formatted + ".00");
    if (formatted == "0") {
      $this.parent().parent().parent().find(".panel-data-value").text("Formula");
    }
  });
  });
})(jQuery);

$(document).on("click",".add-multi",function() {
  $(".multi-list").prepend(tempMulti);
});

$(document).on("click",".multi-list-each-delete",function() {
  $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

```css
.form {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 768px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
 font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #0099ff;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.input-text {
  height: 34px;
  border: solid 1px #c4c4c4;
  width: 366px;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 0 12px 0 12px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  color: #333;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.input-text:focus {
  border: solid 1px #00c983 !important; 
}

::placeholder {
  color: #c4c4c4; 
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: left !important;
}

.form-input-label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  color: #333;
}

.input-disabled {
  background-color: #eee; 
}

.form-unit {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.input-select-btn {
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 34px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: -999;
}

.dropdown-btn-wrapper-clear {
  border-left: solid 1px #c4c4c4; 
}

.input-select-btn i {
  color: #666 !important; 
}

.on-disabled-btn {
  border: solid 1px #c4c4c4;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.input-select-btn i {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #333;
}

.form-row {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.form-divided {
  display: inline-block;
}

.form-divided-left {
  margin-right: 32px;
}

.btn-label {
  background-color: #eee; 
}

.spinner-group {
  position: absolute; 
  width: 16px;
  height: 26px;
  top: 4px;
  right: 44px;
}

.spinner-up,
.spinner-down {
  height: 13px;
  line-height: 13px;
  display: block;
}

.spinner-down {
  top: 12px !important; 
}

.spinner-up i,
.spinner-down i {
  line-height: 13px;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  margin: 0; 
}

.input-with-spinner {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 32px; 
}

#amount-input {
  width: 100% !important; 
}

.amount-spinner-group {
  right: 10px; 
}

.add-multi {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  border: dashed 2px #eaeaea;
  font-size: 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.add-multi:hover {
  background-color: #f8f8f8; 
}

.add-multi i {
  font-size: 10px; 
  transform: translateY(-1px);
  margin-left: 4px;
}

.multi-list-each {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 16px 24px 12px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.multi-list-each input {
  background-color: #fff; 
}

.multi-form-group {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.multi-form-group input { 
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.spinner-group-year {
  right: 2px; 
}

#balance-currency {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.multi-col {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-right: 16px;
  padding-left: 16px;
}

.multi-col:first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.multi-col:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}

.multi-col input {
  margin-bottom: 0; 
}

.multi-list-each-delete {
  position: absolute; 
  right: 24px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.multi-list-each-delete i {
  font-size: 12px; 
}

@media (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 576px) {
  .form {
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-right: 16px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .form-divided-left {
    margin-right: 24px;
  }
  
  .form-divided {
    width: calc(50% - 14px);
  }
  
  .input-text,
  textarea {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .input-select-btn {
    right: 0;
  }
  
  .labeled-row {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .form-unit .select2-container, .form-unit .select2-selection {
      width: 100% !important;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .form {
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-right: 16px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .form-divided {
    display: block; 
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .form-divided-left {
    margin-right: 0; 
  }
  
  .input-text,
  textarea {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .labeled-row {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .form-unit .select2-container, .form-unit .select2-selection {
      width: 100% !important;
  }
  
  .multi-col {
    margin-bottom: 16px; 
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
  }
  
  .multi-list-each-delete {
    bottom: 8px;
    top: auto;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    text-align: center;
    color: #999;
  }
  
  .multi-list-each-delete .button:hover {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #999;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.11/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-p2jx59pefphTFIpeqCcISO9MdVfIm4pNnsL08A6v5vaQc4owkQqxMV8kg4Yvhaw/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="form">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-unit">
      <div class="multi-attribute">
        <label class="form-input-label">Multi-Attributes Input</label>
        <div class="add-multi">Add item <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></div>
        <ul class="multi-list">
          <li class="multi-list-each">
            <div class="col-33 multi-col">
              <label class="form-input-label">Year</label>
              <div class="multi-form-group">
                <input class="year-input input-text input-with-spinner" type="number" min="0" placeholder="Add year">
                <a />
                <div class="spinner-group spinner-group-year">
                  <a class="spinner-up"><i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i></a>
                  <a class="spinner-down"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-33 multi-col">
              <label class="form-input-label">Balance Increase</label>
              <div class="balance-group multi-form-group">
                <input class="balance-input input-text input-with-spinner" type="text" placeholder="Add balance">
                <a />
                <div class="spinner-group spinner-group-year">
                  <a class="spinner-up"><i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i></a>
                  <a class="spinner-down"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-33 multi-col">
              <div class="panel-data panel-data-vertical">
                <div class="panel-data-label">
                  Total Balance
                </div>
                <div class="panel-data-value">
                  Formula
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="multi-list-each-delete"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So instead of voting to close this duplicate you add a code-only answer without any explanation on what the problem is and how to fix it. With that much reputation...

Comment: @Andreas at least he's helpful and not giving me a link to question I don't really understand

Comment: @Rosiana The duplicate has an answer with a real explanation and all the relevant keywords for further investigations: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18144022/402037 - How does this answer here help you to understand the problem and why the answer works?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the onkeyup event with this line...

```
 $(document).on("keyup","#form-amount-input, .balance-group input",
```

You need to create a live event that will fire it even when elements are attached after the event is set.

```js
var tempMulti;

$(document).ready(function() {
  resizeMultiPadding();
  tempMulti = $(".multi-list").html();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  resizeMultiPadding();
});

function resizeMultiPadding() {
  if ($(window).width() >= 576) {
    var padding =  $(window).width() * 0.04;
    $(".multi-col").css({"padding-right": padding + "px"});
    $(".multi-col:last-child").css({"padding-right": "0"});
    $(".multi-list-each-delete").html("<i class='fas fa-trash'></i>");
  }
  else {
    $(".multi-list-each-delete").html("<a class='button footer-btn text-btn'><span><i class='fas fa-trash'></i>Delete</span></a>");
  }
}

$(".spinner-up").click(function() {
  var amount = parseInt($(this).parent().prev().prev().val()) || 0;
  amount += 1;
  $(this).parent().prev().prev().val(amount);
});

$(".spinner-down").click(function() {
  var value = $(this).parent().prev().prev().val();
  var amount = parseInt(value) || 0;
  if (amount > 0) {
    amount -= 1; 
  }
  $(this).parent().prev().prev().val(amount);
});

(function($, undefined) {
  "use strict";
  $(function() {
    var $form = $("#form-amount-input, .balance-group");
    var $input = $form.find("input");
    $(document).on("keyup","#form-amount-input, .balance-group input", function(event) {
    var selection = window.getSelection().toString();
    if (selection !== "") {
      return;
    }
    if ($.inArray(event.keyCode, [38,40,37,39]) !== -1) {
      return;
    }
    var $this = $(this);
    var input = $this.val();
    input = input.replace(/[\D\s\._\-]+/g, "");
    input = input ? parseInt(input, 10) : 0;
    var formatted = input.toLocaleString("en-US");
    $this.val(formatted);
    $this.parent().parent().parent().find(".panel-data-value").text("Formula + " + formatted + ".00");
    if (formatted == "0") {
      $this.parent().parent().parent().find(".panel-data-value").text("Formula");
    }
  });
  });
})(jQuery);

$(".add-multi").click(function() {
  $(".multi-list").prepend(tempMulti);
});

$(".multi-list-each-delete").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

```css
.form {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 768px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
 font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #0099ff;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.input-text {
  height: 34px;
  border: solid 1px #c4c4c4;
  width: 366px;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 0 12px 0 12px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  color: #333;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.input-text:focus {
  border: solid 1px #00c983 !important; 
}

::placeholder {
  color: #c4c4c4; 
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: left !important;
}

.form-input-label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  color: #333;
}

.input-disabled {
  background-color: #eee; 
}

.form-unit {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.input-select-btn {
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 34px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: -999;
}

.dropdown-btn-wrapper-clear {
  border-left: solid 1px #c4c4c4; 
}

.input-select-btn i {
  color: #666 !important; 
}

.on-disabled-btn {
  border: solid 1px #c4c4c4;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.input-select-btn i {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #333;
}

.form-row {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.form-divided {
  display: inline-block;
}

.form-divided-left {
  margin-right: 32px;
}

.btn-label {
  background-color: #eee; 
}

.spinner-group {
  position: absolute; 
  width: 16px;
  height: 26px;
  top: 4px;
  right: 44px;
}

.spinner-up,
.spinner-down {
  height: 13px;
  line-height: 13px;
  display: block;
}

.spinner-down {
  top: 12px !important; 
}

.spinner-up i,
.spinner-down i {
  line-height: 13px;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  margin: 0; 
}

.input-with-spinner {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 32px; 
}

#amount-input {
  width: 100% !important; 
}

.amount-spinner-group {
  right: 10px; 
}

.add-multi {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  border: dashed 2px #eaeaea;
  font-size: 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.add-multi:hover {
  background-color: #f8f8f8; 
}

.add-multi i {
  font-size: 10px; 
  transform: translateY(-1px);
  margin-left: 4px;
}

.multi-list-each {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 16px 24px 12px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.multi-list-each input {
  background-color: #fff; 
}

.multi-form-group {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.multi-form-group input { 
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.spinner-group-year {
  right: 2px; 
}

#balance-currency {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.multi-col {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-right: 16px;
  padding-left: 16px;
}

.multi-col:first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.multi-col:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}

.multi-col input {
  margin-bottom: 0; 
}

.multi-list-each-delete {
  position: absolute; 
  right: 24px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.multi-list-each-delete i {
  font-size: 12px; 
}

@media (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 576px) {
  .form {
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-right: 16px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .form-divided-left {
    margin-right: 24px;
  }
  
  .form-divided {
    width: calc(50% - 14px);
  }
  
  .input-text,
  textarea {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .input-select-btn {
    right: 0;
  }
  
  .labeled-row {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .form-unit .select2-container, .form-unit .select2-selection {
      width: 100% !important;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .form {
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-right: 16px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .form-divided {
    display: block; 
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .form-divided-left {
    margin-right: 0; 
  }
  
  .input-text,
  textarea {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .labeled-row {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .form-unit .select2-container, .form-unit .select2-selection {
      width: 100% !important;
  }
  
  .multi-col {
    margin-bottom: 16px; 
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
  }
  
  .multi-list-each-delete {
    bottom: 8px;
    top: auto;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    text-align: center;
    color: #999;
  }
  
  .multi-list-each-delete .button:hover {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #999;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.11/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-p2jx59pefphTFIpeqCcISO9MdVfIm4pNnsL08A6v5vaQc4owkQqxMV8kg4Yvhaw/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="form">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-unit">
      <div class="multi-attribute">
        <label class="form-input-label">Multi-Attributes Input</label>
        <div class="add-multi">Add item <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></div>
        <ul class="multi-list">
          <li class="multi-list-each">
            <div class="col-33 multi-col">
              <label class="form-input-label">Year</label>
              <div class="multi-form-group">
                <input class="year-input input-text input-with-spinner" type="number" min="0" placeholder="Add year">
                <a />
                <div class="spinner-group spinner-group-year">
                  <a class="spinner-up"><i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i></a>
                  <a class="spinner-down"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-33 multi-col">
              <label class="form-input-label">Balance Increase</label>
              <div class="balance-group multi-form-group">
                <input class="balance-input input-text input-with-spinner" type="text" placeholder="Add balance">
                <a />
                <div class="spinner-group spinner-group-year">
                  <a class="spinner-up"><i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i></a>
                  <a class="spinner-down"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-33 multi-col">
              <div class="panel-data panel-data-vertical">
                <div class="panel-data-label">
                  Total Balance
                </div>
                <div class="panel-data-value">
                  Formula
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="multi-list-each-delete"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var tempMulti;

$(document).ready(function() {
  resizeMultiPadding();
  tempMulti = $(".multi-list").html();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  resizeMultiPadding();
});

function resizeMultiPadding() {
  if ($(window).width() >= 576) {
    var padding =  $(window).width() * 0.04;
    $(".multi-col").css({"padding-right": padding + "px"});
    $(".multi-col:last-child").css({"padding-right": "0"});
    $(".multi-list-each-delete").html("<i class='fas fa-trash'></i>");
  }
  else {
    $(".multi-list-each-delete").html("<a class='button footer-btn text-btn'><span><i class='fas fa-trash'></i>Delete</span></a>");
  }
}

$(document).on("click",".spinner-up",function() {
  var amount = parseInt($(this).parent().prev().prev().val()) || 0;
  amount += 1;
  $(this).parent().prev().prev().val(amount);
});

$(document).on("click",'.spinner-down',function() {
  var value = $(this).parent().prev().prev().val();
  var amount = parseInt(value) || 0;
  if (amount > 0) {
    amount -= 1; 
  }
  $(this).parent().prev().prev().val(amount);
});

(function($, undefined) {
  "use strict";
  $(function() {
    var $form = $("#form-amount-input, .balance-group");
    var $input = $form.find("input");
    $input.on("keyup", function(event) {
    var selection = window.getSelection().toString();
    if (selection !== "") {
      return;
    }
    if ($.inArray(event.keyCode, [38,40,37,39]) !== -1) {
      return;
    }
    var $this = $(this);
    var input = $this.val();
    input = input.replace(/[\D\s\._\-]+/g, "");
    input = input ? parseInt(input, 10) : 0;
    var formatted = input.toLocaleString("en-US");
    $this.val(formatted);
    $this.parent().parent().parent().find(".panel-data-value").text("Formula + " + formatted + ".00");
    if (formatted == "0") {
      $this.parent().parent().parent().find(".panel-data-value").text("Formula");
    }
  });
  });
})(jQuery);

$(".add-multi").click(function() {
  $(".multi-list").prepend(tempMulti);
});

$(".multi-list-each-delete").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

```css
.form {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 768px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
 font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #0099ff;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.input-text {
  height: 34px;
  border: solid 1px #c4c4c4;
  width: 366px;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 0 12px 0 12px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  color: #333;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.input-text:focus {
  border: solid 1px #00c983 !important; 
}

::placeholder {
  color: #c4c4c4; 
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: left !important;
}

.form-input-label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  color: #333;
}

.input-disabled {
  background-color: #eee; 
}

.form-unit {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.input-select-btn {
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 34px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: -999;
}

.dropdown-btn-wrapper-clear {
  border-left: solid 1px #c4c4c4; 
}

.input-select-btn i {
  color: #666 !important; 
}

.on-disabled-btn {
  border: solid 1px #c4c4c4;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.input-select-btn i {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #333;
}

.form-row {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.form-divided {
  display: inline-block;
}

.form-divided-left {
  margin-right: 32px;
}

.btn-label {
  background-color: #eee; 
}

.spinner-group {
  position: absolute; 
  width: 16px;
  height: 26px;
  top: 4px;
  right: 44px;
}

.spinner-up,
.spinner-down {
  height: 13px;
  line-height: 13px;
  display: block;
}

.spinner-down {
  top: 12px !important; 
}

.spinner-up i,
.spinner-down i {
  line-height: 13px;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  margin: 0; 
}

.input-with-spinner {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 32px; 
}

#amount-input {
  width: 100% !important; 
}

.amount-spinner-group {
  right: 10px; 
}

.add-multi {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  border: dashed 2px #eaeaea;
  font-size: 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.add-multi:hover {
  background-color: #f8f8f8; 
}

.add-multi i {
  font-size: 10px; 
  transform: translateY(-1px);
  margin-left: 4px;
}

.multi-list-each {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 16px 24px 12px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.multi-list-each input {
  background-color: #fff; 
}

.multi-form-group {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.multi-form-group input { 
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.spinner-group-year {
  right: 2px; 
}

#balance-currency {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.multi-col {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-right: 16px;
  padding-left: 16px;
}

.multi-col:first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.multi-col:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}

.multi-col input {
  margin-bottom: 0; 
}

.multi-list-each-delete {
  position: absolute; 
  right: 24px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.multi-list-each-delete i {
  font-size: 12px; 
}

@media (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 576px) {
  .form {
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-right: 16px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .form-divided-left {
    margin-right: 24px;
  }
  
  .form-divided {
    width: calc(50% - 14px);
  }
  
  .input-text,
  textarea {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .input-select-btn {
    right: 0;
  }
  
  .labeled-row {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .form-unit .select2-container, .form-unit .select2-selection {
      width: 100% !important;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .form {
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-right: 16px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .form-divided {
    display: block; 
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .form-divided-left {
    margin-right: 0; 
  }
  
  .input-text,
  textarea {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .labeled-row {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .form-unit .select2-container, .form-unit .select2-selection {
      width: 100% !important;
  }
  
  .multi-col {
    margin-bottom: 16px; 
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
  }
  
  .multi-list-each-delete {
    bottom: 8px;
    top: auto;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    text-align: center;
    color: #999;
  }
  
  .multi-list-each-delete .button:hover {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #999;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.11/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-p2jx59pefphTFIpeqCcISO9MdVfIm4pNnsL08A6v5vaQc4owkQqxMV8kg4Yvhaw/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="form">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-unit">
      <div class="multi-attribute">
        <label class="form-input-label">Multi-Attributes Input</label>
        <div class="add-multi">Add item <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></div>
        <ul class="multi-list">
          <li class="multi-list-each">
            <div class="col-33 multi-col">
              <label class="form-input-label">Year</label>
              <div class="multi-form-group">
                <input class="year-input input-text input-with-spinner" type="number" min="0" placeholder="Add year">
                <a />
                <div class="spinner-group spinner-group-year">
                  <a class="spinner-up"><i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i></a>
                  <a class="spinner-down"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-33 multi-col">
              <label class="form-input-label">Balance Increase</label>
              <div class="balance-group multi-form-group">
                <input class="balance-input input-text input-with-spinner" type="text" placeholder="Add balance">
                <a />
                <div class="spinner-group spinner-group-year">
                  <a class="spinner-up"><i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i></a>
                  <a class="spinner-down"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-33 multi-col">
              <div class="panel-data panel-data-vertical">
                <div class="panel-data-label">
                  Total Balance
                </div>
                <div class="panel-data-value">
                  Formula
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="multi-list-each-delete"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you should always add an explanation to your answers to avoid a copy-and-paste generation of developers :)

Comment: i'm new user so i don't know all thing but i forgot to give explanation of my answer ! thank you